# How to setup hostname for email in Oracle APEX 4.2 version

Tags: oracle-apex

I need to setup the hostname for my emails in ORacle APEX 4.2 version. In the later versions we can do it using manage instance but couldn't find a way to do it in APEX 4.2 versions.

Can somebody please help me setup the hostname in order to send the emails.

Thanks,
Abha

Answer (score 0):

In APEX 4.2 version it works the same way..by login to APEX administration --> Manage Instance --> Instance Settings -->Email.